# Visual Studio - Could not edit because it is not in the website

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have a link to some style sheet from the Yahoo Developer Network, this is what I have in the head section of my master page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?2.8.0r4/build/reset/reset-min.css&2.8.0r4/build/base/base-min.css" media="all" />
```

And for some reason Visual Studio (2008 Professional) keeps telling me:

"could not edit 'http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?2.8.0r4/build/reset/reset-min.css&2.8.0r4/build/base/base-min.css' because it is not in the website".

My head tag has a runat="server" attribute so I can't have any code in there to inject the url.

Has anyone managed to get rid of this very useful message?

Comment: What is it that you're doing right before you get this error message? Are you switching from source to design, or you opening a master page up or a content page. I've dropped your stylesheet link into a page and can't get it to do the same thing. More info would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though a definitive solution hasn't been found, a Microsoft guy in [this ASP.NET Forums thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1176284.aspx) is asking for projects that exhibit this issue.

The proposed solutions that may work for you, but haven't worked for me, include:

1. Ensure your CSS file has uniform line endings. Edit menu > Format Document in Visual Studio. Of course, this is hard when the file is on a Yahoo server.
2. Install Visual Studio 2008 SP1.
3. Open Visual Studio first, then open the solution file. (Don't open the solution file directly by double-clicking in Windows Explorer.)

Comment: I've just installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 and the problem seems to be fixed. Thanks!
 
Here's the URL to the VS 2008 SP1 installer... http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a local copy of the stylesheet? Just during development, then switch it back to online source once you're ready for production?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue in referencing the following style sheet, so I wrapped in a Response.Write, after that, the annoying message box stopped appearing.

```
<% Response.Write( @"<link rel=""stylesheet"" href=""http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/base2.css"" type=""text/css"" media=""all"" />" ); %>
```

I had also tried rel="stylesheet nofollow", but IE doesn't like that and will not render properly. The above works fine for FireFox and IE.